# Arduíno com conexão Wifi

Tags: android

Bom dia. Sou no novo aqui e também estou começando com o Arduíno. Como faço para passar os dados coletados no Arduíno via wifi para um celular com Android? Queria criar um aplicativo (Apk). É possível?

Comment: Como você está usando o arduino para se conectar a uma rede ? Você está usando um shield ethernet ? ou wifi ? Em qualquer caso, gerenciar uma conexão direta para o celular, provavelmente não funcionará muito bem, aconselho usar um serviço de fila de mensagens (processamento assíncrono) no estilo do GCM da google.

Comment: Quero passar um vídeo através da rede. O arduíno estaria conectado a rede wifi da casa, e enviaria o vídeo pelo celular. Entendeu?